# jasper plugin not getting installed in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to install jasper studio from eclipse Luna. And getting the below error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Problems downloading artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext,2.12.0.v20170518-0959. Unpacking fails
>   because intermediate file is empty:
>   C:\Users\deekusu\AppData\Local\Temp\work7940700163830740449\p2.optimizers.incoming4050107016080238302.jar
>   Problems downloading artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.builder,2.12.0.v20170519-0809. Unpacking
>   fails because intermediate file is empty:
>   C:\Users\deekusu\AppData\Local\Temp\work8278234492382614758\p2.optimizers.incoming5583515848131428105.jar
>   Problems downloading artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types,2.12.0.v20170519-0752.

After doing some research I tried to install xtext software from https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html

But it is also failing with same error.

Java version =1.7 (64 bit)
Eclipse and windows os -64 Bit

I tried installing with Mars/Photon/Neon/Indigo.. But still getting the same error.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you install [Xtext via Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-xtext)? As workaround you can directly download the [_Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers_](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/1/eclipse-dsl-oxygen-1-win32-x86_64.zip) package which contains Xtext.

Comment: eclipse download servers are stable like a jenga tower after 20 mins of gameplay => simply retrying at a later point might helt

Comment: @ChristianDietrich See http://status.eclipse.org

Comment: @howlger, jasperstudio latest version needs xtext 2.12, but market place has 2.11. But I tried installing 2.12 from eclipse using the https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html. I also tried Java and DSL IDE, that also have the same problem. Below is the error:Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.core,2.12.0.v20170519-0902.
Unpacking fails because intermediate file is empty: C:\Users\deekusu\AppData\Local\Temp\work7636682668167609315\p2.optimizers.incoming6485572878445051517.jar

Comment: i just have it a try and it worked fine. in doubt you can download the complete repo as well. https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/downloads/

Comment: @DeepakRanga Is always the same artifact empty (in the question it was [org.eclipse.xtext.common.types,2.12.0.v20170519-0752](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.12.0/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext.common.types_2.12.0.v20170519-0752.jar))? In case of a slow internet connection try to add followings two lines to the end of your `eclipse.ini` file: `-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=8400` and `-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=8400`.

Comment: @howlger, There are couple of other artifacts having the same problem. I have downloaded the fullsite.zip from the sourceforge for jasper studio with old version so it will not use xtext latest version and then used that zip to install jasper studio in eclipse and it resolves the issue.

Comment: @DeepakRanga If you want to find out the root cause, try to increase the timeouts for downloading (see my last comment).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. First you need to install Xtext from eclipse markeplace, then you can install Jaspersoft Studio.